# EF dynamic proxies in Session Azure Cache

Tags: entity-framework, session, azure

We're working with Entity Framework in a Windows Azure environment and till now we were using InProc session state, but as some of you might know, due to it's distributed nature we should use another method, that's why we activated the Azure AppFabric Cache.

When activating this session state provider we started having the following exception:

```
ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.]
       System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +11658009
       System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +66
       System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption) +271
       System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad() +499
       System.Data.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty(TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject) +136
       System.Data.Objects.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy proxy, TItem item) +153
       System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SysUser_1A4439A55EAE70AD5C976139AA3A390B54A2C96E5FA605B3F364F0ADF52D0707.get_Assignments() +151
       WriteSysUser_1A4439A55EAE70AD5C976139AA3A390B54A2C96E5FA605B3F364F0ADF52D0707ToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract ) +544
...
```

This exception seems to be thrown when the AppFabric tries to serialize an EF object to cache.

We're using EF with LazyLoading and ProxyCreation flags both active, and this does not seem to be supported in this scenario, but it was in InProc Session state management.

We're looking for some suggestions on how to use Azure AppFabric Session State provider with EF, while maintaining lazy loading.

Thanks,
Rui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use lazy loading and dynamic proxies with any kind of session. If it worked with InProc it was either due to invalid handling of EF context lifetime or you was just lucky and accessed the cached object only in scope of its context.

Lazy loading requires living context and context should live only to perform single unit of work. Because of that you cannot have requirement to support lazy loading on cached entities. Cached entities should not be proxied (proxy doesn't make sense for them) at all and must be detached.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, regarding it working when using InProc session my only guess is that the serialization is done in a different way, since it seems to be where the error is thrown, and the only thing we've changed in the project was the Session configuration, from InProc to Azure cache, all the other logic is the same.
Since we still want to have lazy loading, is it possible to store entities in session? If so, the way to do it is first detaching them? How can we do that?

Comment: InProc session doesn't use any serialization. It just holds reference to existing object. You can detach entity simply by calling `Detach` on the context but once you do it it will not allow lazy loading any more and that is the point - entity stored in session cannot use lazy loading later on.

Comment: I understand that after caching the lazy loading on those entities is not available anymore. Simply calling detach before sending an entity to session doesn't seem to be working. To make it more clear, my goal now is to while maintaining lazy loading in the rest of the logic, have the ability to store some EF entities to session with the basic properties (real POCOs). Do you know a way of achieving this without creating new classes?

Comment: You can turn off lazy loading or proxy creation selectively at runtime (check `ContextOptions` property). You know that some entity will be passed to cache so use the context configured to not use proxy creation for its loading and rest of your application can still use context configured to use proxies and lazy loading. Btw. doesn't seem to be working is not description of the problem.

Comment: Just detaching was not working since I still had some (different deserialization errors like "The property XX on type YY cannot be set because the collection is already set to an EntityCollection.").
Turning off lazy loading at runtime, being a local thing it will still prevent its usage in the current context scope. I think I will have to find another approach to store some of this information in session.